# Plotting densities with seaborn and latex error

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, seaborn

I'm trying to plot densities graphs from some data, using seaborn.

It works fine without latex, but when I try to plot with latex, it gives me an error.

Here are the settings:

```
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rcParams.update()
sns.set_context("paper")
sns.set(font_scale=1.5, rc={'text.usetex' : True})
sns.set_style('white', {'font.family':'serif', 'font.serif':'Times New Roman', 'background':'white'})
sns.despine()
```

and the graph is being plotted with:

```
sns.kdeplot(np.array(data), bw=0.4, cut=0)
plt.tight_layout(True)
plt.savefig('file.png', dpi=300)
```

Here is the error:

```
  File "plotGraphs.py", line 214, in <module>
    plotCarsReached()
  File "plotGraphs.py", line 118, in plotCarsReached
    plt.tight_layout(True)
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1337, in tight_layout
    gcf().tight_layout(pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 358, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2491, in tight_layout
    kwargs = get_tight_layout_figure(
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 355, in get_tight_layout_figure
    kwargs = auto_adjust_subplotpars(fig, renderer,
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 109, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
    tight_bbox_raw = union([ax.get_tightbbox(renderer) for ax in subplots
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 109, in <listcomp>
    tight_bbox_raw = union([ax.get_tightbbox(renderer) for ax in subplots
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 4317, in get_tightbbox
    bb_xaxis = self.xaxis.get_tightbbox(renderer)
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1197, in get_tightbbox
    bboxes = [
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1198, in <genexpr>
    *(a.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 905, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 299, in _get_layout
    w, h, d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 203, in get_text_width_height_descent
    w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 451, in get_text_width_height_descent
    with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
  File "/Users/iMac/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py", line 198, in __init__
    self.file = open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/iMac/.matplotlib/tex.cache/bff659c457d4aecfc8f90b11c18fa8b1.dvi'
```

If I remove the initial settings, the plot works.
Other plots using matplotlib instead of seaborn works as well.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I believe the lines with "usetex" are triggering the error. If I remove them, I can save the plot, but without all the necessary settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but was able to fix it. The issue is python is not finding latex and kpsewhich files. I resolved the issue by performing the following steps on a Mac and using PyCharm:

1. Install all recommended packages by Matplotlib [latex](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/text/usetex.html)

*brew cask install mactex ghostscript*

2. Manually add latex bin directory path to $PYTHONPATH at the begining in .bash_profile

*export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64darwin:/usr/local/bin:$PYTHONPATH"*

Worked like a charm - the Matplotlib example output:
[Text rendering With LaTeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdssX.png)

*Hack to force PyCharm to update it's environment
In the "Run/Edit Configurations":
First uncheck "Add content roots to PYTHONPATH", run it, it will complain about something.. 
Then check it back on, and run again. This triggers some kind of update about the paths in the target environment*

Comment: I don't think this example uses seaborn. I did what you said, but the error persists.. I am able to plot graphs using latex and matplotlib. The problem is when the graph is generated through seaborn

Answer (score 0):

The error was appearing because I had a '%' in one of the axis labels, and I didn't change it to '\%' when I tried to plot it with latex..